# Is there a list to compare the properties of items between two lists?

Tags: c#, list, linq

Basically I want to do the following:

```
        List<myClass> list1;
        List<myClass> list2;
        List<myClass> listOfDifferences;

        ...

        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++ )
        {
            if (list1[i].myAwesomeProperty != list2[i].myAwesomeProperty)
            {
                listOfDifferences.Add(list1[i]);
            }
        }
```

Is there a way of doing this without using a for loop? In my case I know that the two lists are identical, only the values of one property of the objects can vary. Apart from that, each list holds the same amount of objects in the same order. 
As far as I know, LINQ would be preferable if usable in such a case, right?

Comment: You won't get rid of the loop but you could avoid using an explicit `for` loop by following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594000/f-list-map-equivalent-in-c)

Comment: Unless you're doing something really dumb, will `list1[i].myAwesomeProperty != list1[i].myAwesomeProperty` ever be true? AKAIK, only if it's a floating point `NaN`

Comment: You can use the `Except` method in Linq which produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @spender whoaps, my bad, edited the question.

Comment: If the idea is to compare items as the same index in the two lists then you could just `Zip` (note it will stop on whichever list is shorter)  `var diff = list1.Zip(list2, (x,y) => new{First=x,Second=y}).Where(z => z.First.Prop != z.Second.Prop).Select(z => z.First).ToList();`

Comment: For loops are mostly faster then linq in terms of performance

Comment: I agree with @Amitchauhan, the for loop is probably the most performant option. It is also clear what your intentions are using the for loop. I see no need for linq here.

Comment: @Kevin As a heavy LINQ(-to-objects) user, I believe that the avoidance of loops means less boiler-plate, less opportunity to write incorrect code and therefore less bugs, not more. If correctness is the goal (it is), LINQ has served me very well on this front. Notwithstanding, if (after measurement), the LINQ isn't fast enough, sometimes a hand-rolled loop can squeeze something extra.

Comment: @spender - Don't get me wrong, I am a huge fan of LINQ and use it extensively. My two exceptions are when peformance is sometimes crtical, and if I feel the code is more readable not using LINQ. I'm sure there are a ton of other opinions also which I think he was asking for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ordering is guaranteed, then by zipping the two lists together, you can do the following:

```
var diffs = list1.Zip(list2, (item1, item2) => (item1, item2))
    .Where(x => x.item1.myAwesomeProperty != x.item2.myAwesomeProperty)
    .Select(x => x.item1); //.ToList()
```

If `ValueTuple` isn't available at your language level, then use anonymous object instead:

```
var diffs = list1.Zip(list2, (item1, item2) => new{item1, item2})
    .Where(x => x.item1.myAwesomeProperty != x.item2.myAwesomeProperty)
    .Select(x => x.item1); //.ToList()
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks! The only question that remains: Is this solution preferable/good practice vs. the loop I used in my question?

Comment: @RolandDeschain As discussed in my last comment to your original question, by recomposing the solution as LINQ, I believe that you have code that easier to verify as correct. Rather than dealing with the mechanics of iteration (the "how"), it allows you to focus on the specific transformations you want to apply (the "what"). I very rarely write `for` loops for non-mutating queries (although there are always [exceptions](https://github.com/biggyspender/BkTree/blob/master/BkTree/BkTree.cs#L80) to this preference when it makes sense).

Comment: @RolandDeschain - There isn't a definitive answer to that question. I prefer the for loop because I find it more readable in this case, and spender pefers LINQ. You might find someone else who suggests a Paralle.For.